# How to skip first regex match?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

Is there anyway to skip the first match when using regex and php.

Or is there some way of achieveing this using str_replace.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I am trying to remove all the instances of a string from another string but I want to retain the first occurance e.g

```
$toRemove = 'test';
$string = 'This is a test string to test to removing the word test';
```

**Ouput string would be:**

This is a test string to <strike>test</strike> to removing the word <strike>test</strike>

Comment: Paste your regex and example of date you are using.

Comment: Do you want to match only the 2nd occurrence or all occurrences after the first?

Comment: Regex:   `\\[n@.*?\\]`

@webbiedave - I want to match all the occurances except the first.

Comment: Is this part of a `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Yes this is part of preg_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy PHP way:

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/an/i";
    $text = "banANA";
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches, 0, $matches[0][1]);
    echo $matches[0];
?>
```

will give you "AN".

**UPDATE**: Didn't know it was a replace. Try this:

```
<?php
    $toRemove = 'test';
    $string = 'This is a test string to test to removing the word test';
    preg_match("/$toRemove/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $newString = preg_replace("/$toRemove/", "", $string);
    $newString = substr_replace($newString, $matches[0][0], $matches[0][1], 0);
    echo $newString;
?>
```

Find the first match and remember where it was, then delete everything, then put whatever was in the first spot back in.

Comment: Eh, thought of a cleverer way.

    <?php
        $toRemove = 'test';
        $string = 'This is a test string to test to removing the word test';
        $found = 0;
        echo preg_replace("/($toRemove)/e", '$found++ ? \'\' : \'$1\'', $string);
    ?>

Comment: for the cleverer way, found is always 1 for me no matter how many matches there are, so it doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('/((?:^.*?\btest\b)?.*?)\btest\b/', '$1', $string);
```

The idea is to match and capture whatever *precedes* each match, and plug it back in.  `(?:^.*?test)?` causes the *first* instance of `test` to be included in the capture.  (All the `\b`s are to avoid partial-word matches, like the `test` in `smartest` or `testify`.)

Comment: I just love you. https://twitter.com/tomasdev/status/640273963688574977 - this is the best way ever to convert repeated query parameters to comma-separated single ones.

Answer (score 0):

assume 'blah' is your regex pattern, blah(blah) will match and capture the second one

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it might be usefull to people.

```
$string = "This is a test string to test something with the word test and replacing test";
$replace = "test";
$tmp = explode($replace, $string);
$tmp[0] .= $replace;
$newString = implode('', $tmp);
echo $newString; // Output: This is a test string to something with the word and replacing
```