# Replace a string starting on 2nd

Tags: php, regex

How can I replace a string, using normal replace or regular expression to replace only the 2nd found result onwards

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
codes

<div id="fb-root"></div>

aas
<div id="fb-root"></div>
ss
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Expected results should be

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
codes


aas
ss
```

the 2nd fb-root div upto the last should be removed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: dont include it on the page on the first place

Comment: Yes, I don't want it to have as 3 divs. but there is a reason why there are 4 on this project, which unfortunately I cant change.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do this, but why not use a placeholder for the first one, replace the rest, then change the placeholder back?

```
$full_text = file_get_contents($filename);
$text_to_replace = '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
$placeholder = '__PLACEHOLDER__';

$full_text = str_replace($text_to_replace, $placeholder, $full_text, 1);
$full_text = str_replace($text_to_replace, '', $full_text);
$full_text = str_replace($placeholder, $text_to_replace, $full_text);
```

The key here is the fourth parameter in the first call to `str_replace`, which tells the function to only replace one instance of the searched text. It will replace only the first instance with the placeholder, then the second call will remove all remaining instances, and the third call will replace the placeholder with the original text.

Comment: Thanks, yes thats possible. but 3 replacement might be a bit slower. let's wait for other suggestion.

Comment: It's your call, of course, but this sounds like a premature optimization. Performing a couple of replacements would take just a few microseconds on any reasonably sized file.

Comment: +1, yes your answer is what I typically use.
I'm not optimizing just for this, just wanted to recall the other regex trick to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$str = 'STRING HERE';
$result = preg_replace_callback('@<div\s+id="fb-root"></div>@', function(){
    static $count = 0;
    if(++$count > 1){
        return null;
    }else{
        $args = func_get_arg(0);
        return $args[0];
    }
}, $str);
```

Comment: I remember before there were some regex modifier/trick that can be used

Comment: In that case take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850092/skip-first-regex-match

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$str = "...";

$needle = '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
$len = strlen($needle);
$pos = strpos($str, $needle) + $len; // skip the first occurance
while (($pos = strpos($str, $needle, $pos)) !== false)
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . substr($str, $pos + $len);// remove the needle
```