# PHP Regex Skip First Match

Tags: php, regex

I Have following data :

```
<h5> MY DATA </h5>
» Test data1
» Test data2
» Test data3
```

And I wish to match all ' »' except the first. But the various regex that i've tried do not work. Kindly advice some solution.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850092/skip-first-regex-match

Comment: Hi Pendo, thanks for your reply. But that is a work around - since it first finds the first match and position, then delete everything, then put whatever was in the first spot back in.
I was wondering if there was something within a single regex that could solve the problem.
http://regexr.com?374h8

Comment: There is another answer that is fully regex (the 2nd post on the page)

Comment: `But the various regex that i've tried do not work` well then show us what you have tried and why it did fail. Also please be precise, what if there was another random line like `foobar` between `» Test data1` and `» Test data2`. Would it be matched or not ?

Comment: Hi HamZa,
Thnx for replying. No the line will not be matched. Only the symbols. Skipping first.
I tried (?:^»)(.*)(»), ?!^.?)(»), ...etc

Comment: My Basic aim is : 
I have to replace : `»` by `<br>»`
But I have to skip the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^>\s]\h*\R\K(?=»)~', '<br/>', $string);
```

details:

```
[^>\s]  # a character that is not a white char or a > (to avoid the first line)
\h*     # horizontal white chars zero or more times (possible leading spaces)
\R      # a new line
\K      # remove all that have been matched before
(?=»)   # lookahead assertion, to check if there is a » after
```

The goal of the pattern is to match an empty string at the good position in the string.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. tried out a few solutions including this.. but couldn't get it to work... Finally went for a workaround for the break issue not related to the symbol, but identifying the newlines : `/(^[\rn]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/`

Answer (score 2):

But *why* do you want to match every `»` except the first one?  You'll get much better responses if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, not how you're trying to accomplish it.

As I understand it, you have a block of two or more lines that start with a certain character and you want to add a `<br/>` tag to the end of every line except the last one.  When you describe it that way, the regex practically writes itself:

```
^        # beginning of line (in multiline mode)
(».+\R)  # `»` and the rest of the line, including the trailing newline (`\R`)
(?=»)    # lookahead checks that the next line begins with `»`, too
```

The line is captured in group #1, so we plug it back into the replacement string and add the `<br/>` tag:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(».+\R)(?=»)/m', '$1<br/>', $subject);
```

I'm not fluent in PHP, but it's possible you'll need to add the UTF8 modifier (`/^(».+\R)(?=»)/mu`) or use a hex escape for the `»` character (`/^(\x{BB}.+\R)(?=\x{BB})/m`).

Comment: Nice regex-fu but there is a little misunderstanding. He wants to match every `»` except the *first* one and not the *last* one :)

Comment: D'oh!  The word "last" in my first sentence should have been "first".  But the reasoning still applies.  He's trying to add `»` to the beginning of all but the first line, which is the same as adding it to the *end* of all but the *last* line.  And if you think about it in those terms, it becomes much easier to see your way to a solution, or so I believe.