# Avoid replace placeholder found in replacement string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

let's say i have this string:

```
"my string ? other string ?"
```

- I want to replace the first "?" with `"first param ?"` (note the placeholder ? inside the text)
- and the second `"second param".`

IF i do a preg_replace i obtain this:

```
my string first param second param other string ?
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^
                WRONG                    NOT REPLACED
```

Basically since the first replacement has also the placeholder, `preg_replace` is stupid enough to replace that placeholder, instead of the real second one at the end.

Code with `preg_replace`:

```
$search = ["?", "?"];
$params = ["first param ?", "second param"];
$query ="first text ? other text ?";

//> Marker in the query are ?, so I create the array to preg_replace
$search = array_fill(0,count($params),'/\?/');
$query = preg_replace(
    $search,                // a list of ?
    $params,                // escaped values
    $query,                 // from query
    1                       // replace only 1 time
);
//output: first text first param second param other text ?
```

Any hint on how to avoid searching the placeholder inside the replacement ?

Live code with `preg_replace`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e705ba454d030103344bc826e0fe0bf42d5b7b90

Doesn't work also with `str_replace`

```
$search = ["?", "?"];
$params = ["first param ?", "second param"];
$query ="first text ? other text ?";

$query = str_replace ($search, $params, $query);
echo $query;

// output: first text first param second param other text first param second param
```

Live code with str_replace:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc259325411ee42de759f145eac78b339f329f74

### Excepted output

Given:

```
$search = ["?", "?"];
$params = ["first param ?", "second param"];
$query ="first text ? other text ?";
```

The expected output is:

```
first text first param ? other text second param
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
         first placeholder         second placeholder
```

### Excepted output with 3 params

```
$search = ["?", "?", "?"];
$params = ["first param", "second param ?", "third param"];
$query ="first text ? other text ? other chunk ?";
```

The expected output is:

```
first text first param other text  second param ? other chunk third param
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^
         first placeholder         second placeholder         third placeholder
```

### My custom solution

I have come up with a possibile solution using `preg_split`, but honestly this is so hacky there must be something better:

```
 $parts = preg_split('/(\?)/', $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

 foreach($parts as $k=>&$v) {
        // if is odd, then it's a placeholder
        if ($k%2 == 1)
            $v = $params[$k/2];  // replace placeholder with a param
 }

 $query = implode('',$parts);
```

Comment: What if you remove the limit `, 1`?

Comment: tried, doesn't work because it replace both placeholder two times, I have added a live code test in my original post

Comment: do you want to use `str_replace()`? see demo for that https://3v4l.org/t4QKq

Comment: Tried with str_replace and it doesn't work beacuse it replaces multiple times the same placeholer: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b701e18047c2adcf47036cfba6a6b15734c69ee8

Comment: what is your expected output on your given sandbox example?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny: i have added the expected output at the end of my post

Comment: sorry to ask but but are you tring to create something for mySql

Comment: Tito: no it's similar but not sql

Comment: To all: i have added my possibile solution while we were speaking (find it below) it uses preg_split, but honestly it's something very bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any custom replacement logic should be implemented with `preg_replace_callback`, for example:

```
$params = ["first param", "second param ?", "third param"];
$query ="first text ? other text ? other chunk ?";

echo preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($m) use (&$params) {
    return array_shift($params);
}, $query);
```

Live code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33f4804b49103e54e8070e8d9959ec9642930857

Comment: Nice let me create a live snippet, done. Very nice, althou it's not a "custom" replacemnet logic, it's just a very simple sequential placeholder replacement :)

Comment: I was just updated my answer with the same. You have my point.

Answer (score 1):

## This will work only for 2 placeholders.

```
$search = [
    "/^([^?]*)\?/",     # matches everything that is not a question mark in group 1, then a question mark
    "/^(.*)\?/"         # matches everything until last question mark in group 1, then a question mark
];
$params = ["$1first param ?", "$1second param"];

$query = "first text ? other text ?";

$query = preg_replace($search, $params, $query);

echo $query;
```

**Output:**

```
first text first param ? other text second param
```

Comment: Toto +1, but this stuff is dynamic, i don't know how many `$search` will arrive in this function. It needs to be generic

Comment: @giò: Could you give examples and expected result for 3 or more placeholders? with

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a `while()` loop with a check on `strpos()` but also `explode()` is another solution to this problem:

```
$params = ['first param ?', 'second param'];
$query = 'my string ? other string ?';
$str = '';

foreach(explode('?', $query, count($params) + 1) as $token) {
    $str .= $token . array_shift($params);
}

echo $str;
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/ErMJn)

Comment: yes +1, the explode is similar to preg_slit, alto by watching the snippet i think the accepted answer is the simplest solution

Comment: Yes but the difference is that there is no PCRE layer involved in `explode()` as it happens in `preg_split()` or other `preg_*` functions. So it should perform faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$s = "my string ? other string ?";
$s = preg_replace('/\?/', "first ?", $s, 1);
$s = preg_replace('/((?:^.*?\?)?.*?)\?/', "$1second text", $s);
echo $s;
```

Based in [How to skip first regex match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850092/how-to-skip-first-regex-match)